# Is it possible to get the name of saved views of nwd models in Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm aware that it's possible to get the cameras from saved views in the Navisworks models, but it would be great to get the names as well. When uploading a nwd file to a BIM 360 Document Management project these saved views are shown. Is it possible to do this with the Froge viewer as well? Or is this a Document Manager feaure only?
Regards Frode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The saved views in Navisworks files are fetchable with viewpoint names inside the response of the [GET:urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/). Here is an example from the Revit house sample model, `rac_basic_sample_project.rvt` exported as `rac_basic_sample_project.nwc`, see the folder type `folder` JSON object:

[image]

```
{
    "guid": "dc74c06c-0818-46c3-b9cd-6f9666468d12",
    "type": "view",
    "role": "3d",
    "name": "Default",
    "status": "success",
    "camera": [
        -37.01164245605469,
        -573.8855590820312,
        10.432775497436523,
        -37.01164245605469,
        -101.42298889160156,
        10.432775497436523,
        0,
        -2.220446049250313e-16,
        1,
        1,
        0.785398006439209,
        1,
        0
    ],
    "useAsDefault": true,
    "hasThumbnail": "true",
    "children": [
        {
            "guid": "59d18972-95cb-4845-a116-55a92e3c7ac3",
            "type": "resource",
            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGt3ZWo3eHBiZ3A2M3g0aGwzMzV5Nm0yNm9ha2dnb2YyMDE3MDUyOHQwMjQ3MzIzODZ6L3JhY19iYXNpY19zYW1wbGVfcHJvamVjdC5ud2M/output/0/0_100.png",
            "role": "thumbnail",
            "mime": "image/png",
            "resolution": [
                100,
                100
            ]
        },
        {
            "guid": "14607723-303c-476a-ac39-8f66cac8f4bf",
            "type": "resource",
            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGt3ZWo3eHBiZ3A2M3g0aGwzMzV5Nm0yNm9ha2dnb2YyMDE3MDUyOHQwMjQ3MzIzODZ6L3JhY19iYXNpY19zYW1wbGVfcHJvamVjdC5ud2M/output/0/0_200.png",
            "role": "thumbnail",
            "mime": "image/png",
            "resolution": [
                200,
                200
            ]
        },
        {
            "guid": "d7fd06cb-4ef5-48df-9e27-297343bf107a",
            "type": "resource",
            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGt3ZWo3eHBiZ3A2M3g0aGwzMzV5Nm0yNm9ha2dnb2YyMDE3MDUyOHQwMjQ3MzIzODZ6L3JhY19iYXNpY19zYW1wbGVfcHJvamVjdC5ud2M/output/0/0_400.png",
            "role": "thumbnail",
            "mime": "image/png",
            "resolution": [
                400,
                400
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "guid": "cccca659-8638-4e8d-9554-223f7cc4a23b",
    "type": "folder",
    "name": "3D View",
    "role": "viewable",
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "status": "success",
    "progress": "0% complete",
    "children": [
        {
            "guid": "3dc842c3-acf9-4921-8d54-ffebf86500d1",
            "type": "view",
            "role": "3d",
            "name": "Kitchen",
            "camera": [
                -71.70982360839844,
                -77.9845199584961,
                4.921259880065918,
                10.964564323425293,
                -15.158869743347168,
                4.921259880065918,
                4.996003610813204e-16,
                -4.440892098500626e-16,
                1,
                1,
                0.9272952079772949,
                1,
                0
            ],
            "status": "success"
        },
        {
            "guid": "716c2341-af18-4866-9fb7-57a27ff811d3",
            "type": "view",
            "role": "3d",
            "name": "From Yard",
            "camera": [
                -98.73897552490234,
                -169.06787109375,
                0,
                -42.515201568603516,
                -44.77614212036133,
                -1.609189127435573e-14,
                0,
                1.1102230246251565e-16,
                1,
                1,
                0.9272952079772949,
                1,
                0
            ],
            "status": "success"
        },
        {
            "guid": "1466f07a-5536-4acd-bb51-ee228fb6a41e",
            "type": "view",
            "role": "3d",
            "name": "Living Room",
            "camera": [
                -31.575815200805664,
                -51.19736862182617,
                0.9842519760131836,
                38.432044982910156,
                -143.84164428710938,
                0.9842519760131836,
                -5.0237591864288333e-14,
                -3.735900477863652e-14,
                1,
                1,
                0.9272952079772949,
                1,
                0
            ],
            "status": "success"
        },
        {
            "guid": "68ffe8dc-9a9c-45a5-aaf5-29221dd38771",
            "type": "view",
            "role": "3d",
            "name": "Approach",
            "camera": [
                -41.0597038269043,
                38.65303039550781,
                32.80839920043945,
                -49.91415786743164,
                -107.17664337158203,
                9.272088050842285,
                -0.009639321826398373,
                -0.15875616669654846,
                0.9872707724571228,
                1,
                0.9272952079772949,
                1,
                0
            ],
            "status": "success"
        },
        {
            "guid": "4c8b4f68-7010-47eb-a3e3-3aa699e82674",
            "type": "view",
            "role": "3d",
            "name": "Section Perspective",
            "camera": [
                8.170970916748047,
                29.014333724975586,
                5.741469860076904,
                -82.0259780883789,
                -107.69042205810547,
                5.741469860076904,
                7.771561172376096e-16,
                2.914335439641036e-16,
                1,
                1,
                0.9272952079772949,
                1,
                0
            ],
            "status": "success"
        },
        {
            "guid": "33f941f3-81d1-41c5-82e5-346731d79f34",
            "type": "view",
            "role": "3d",
            "name": "Solar Analysis",
            "camera": [
                62.19073486328125,
                -142.4400634765625,
                161.65139770507812,
                -32.913902282714844,
                -97.60645294189453,
                8.838506698608398,
                -0.7451809644699097,
                0.3512883186340332,
                0.5668349266052246,
                1,
                45,
                273.4084777832031,
                1
            ],
            "status": "success"
        },
        {
            "guid": "41b33c50-bcdf-4f57-8101-5f8af6ece8eb",
            "type": "view",
            "role": "3d",
            "name": "{3D}",
            "camera": [
                -104.73332977294922,
                -202.08343505859375,
                67.68977355957031,
                -103.85852813720703,
                -103.78852081298828,
                5.5336480140686035,
                0.004756217356771231,
                0.5344184637069702,
                0.8452067375183105,
                1,
                45,
                424.3688049316406,
                1
            ],
            "status": "success"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now we use the `Kitchen` view to illustrate the workflow:

```
{
    "guid": "3dc842c3-acf9-4921-8d54-ffebf86500d1",
    "type": "view",
    "role": "3d",
    "name": "Kitchen",
    "camera": [
        -71.70982360839844,
        -77.9845199584961,
        4.921259880065918,
        10.964564323425293,
        -15.158869743347168,
        4.921259880065918,
        4.996003610813204e-16,
        -4.440892098500626e-16,
        1,
        1,
        0.9272952079772949,
        1,
        0
    ],
    "status": "success"
}
```

First, let's convert it from original model space into the viewer's:

```
const nwVP = JSON.parse( // the above JSON );
const camera = nwVP.camera;
const nwVPName = nwVP.name;

const placementWithOffset = viewer.model.getData().placementWithOffset;

const pos = new THREE.Vector3( camera[0], camera[1], camera[2] );
const target = new THREE.Vector3( camera[3], camera[4], camera[5] );
const up = new THREE.Vector3( camera[6], camera[7], camera[8] );
const aspect = camera[9];
const fov = camera[10] / Math.PI * 180;
const orthoScale = camera[11];
const isPerspective = !camera[12];

const offsetPos = pos.applyMatrix4( placementWithOffset );
const offsetTarget = target.applyMatrix4( placementWithOffset );

const nwSavedViewpoints = [];
nwSavedViewpoints.push(
    {
        aspect: aspect,
        isPerspective: isPerspective,
        fov: fov,
        position: offsetPos,
        target: offsetTarget,
        up: up,
        orthoScale: orthoScale,
        name: nwVPName
    }
);
```

Afterward, switch the viewpoint by

```
viewer.impl.setViewFromCamera( nwSavedViewpoints[0] );
```

Lastly, you may be aware the above converted camera definition will have the almost same value (floating precision issue) as `viewer.model.getData().cameras[1]`

[image]
[image]

Hope it helps!

Cheers,

**Updates for sectioning mapping**

If your saved viewpoint contains a section plane, the response of [GET:urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) would have something like this:

```
{
    "guid": "54794b24-d9ef-4a1a-b5aa-8bbf35de2c55",
    "type": "view",
    "role": "3d",
    "name": "Section Test",
    "camera": [
        -264.2721252441406,
        -79.92520141601562,
        148.0021209716797,
        -42.678688049316406,
        -73.8739013671875,
        0.7752543091773987,
        0.5530436635017395,
        0.01510258112102747,
        0.8330153822898865,
        1.4948216676712036,
        0.785398006439209,
        1,
        0
    ],
    "sectionPlane": [
        -0.803684066258349,
        -0.5950562340169588,
        0,
        -92.04215879314862
    ],
    "status": "success"
}
```

The `sectionPlane` attribute is the target we want. So, the conversion is

```
const forge_model_offset = viewer.model.getData().globalOffset;

// assume the param of Navisworks clip plane is available
//I copied from the response of the GET:urn/manifest
const navis_clip_plane = { x: -0.803684066258349, y: -0.5950562340169588, z: 0,d:-92.04215879314862 };

//calculate exact distance in Forge Viewer
const dis_in_forge =( forge_model_offset.x * navis_clip_plane.x  +   
                        forge_model_offset.y * navis_clip_plane.y + 
                        forge_model_offset.z * navis_clip_plane.z) + navis_clip_plane.d;

const cutplanes = [
    new THREE.Vector4( navis_clip_plane.x, navis_clip_plane.y, navis_clip_plane.z, dis_in_forge ) 
];

//apply the plane to sectioning
viewer.setCutPlanes( cutplanes )
```

Comment: This looks very promising! Will any sections set in Navisworks be available as well?

Comment: I have updated my answer for converting the section plane, please check above.