# Navisworks saved viewpoints in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk-navisworks

I am trying to follow the instructions in [this blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/saved-viewpoint-navisworks-file-forge-viewer) to access saved viewpoints from a translated Navisworks file in the viewer. However the call

```
presets_cams = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().cameras
```

does not return the viewpoint display names with the viewpoint data, nor does it convey the Navisworks folder structure. How can I associate the viewpoint data with particular viewpoint names from Navisworks?

Comment: When I wrote this blog, it looked to me all camera data are from the extracted file:CameraList.bin, while when Forge Viewer initializes model.getData().cameras, viewpoint name is not set. I do not see any API to read CameraList.bin.  I will double check with engineer team if there is any way in new release.  If no, another alternative is to take advantage of Navisworks viewpoints XML: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/load-xml-navisworks-saved-viewpoints-forge-viewer-cameras

Comment: FYI, another way is to parse camera data inside the response of the [GET:urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/), here is the whole work path. Hope it helps!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804124/7745569

Comment: thanks @EasonKang!  @jacobmlovelace, then it could be an alternative as it does not require to depend on Navisworks (the second blog I mentioned). Could you check if the alternative could help you?

Answer (score 0):

> FYI, another way is to parse camera data inside the response of the GET:urn/manifest, here is the whole work path. Hope it helps! stackoverflow.com/a/55804124/7745569 – Eason Kang 5 hours ago

This worked like a charm. Thank you!