# Applying Navisworks saved viewpoints to the Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-navisworks

I followed the instructions outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55799023/is-it-possible-to-get-the-name-of-saved-views-of-nwd-models-in-forge/55804124) to apply Navisworks saved viewpoints in the Forge viewer. however, I have recently noticed an interesting behavior: Any viewpoints that were oriented to plan north apply correctly at first, then immediately flip 180 degrees to orient to plan south facing upward. Saved viewpoints that are not oriented to plan north work as expected. What might be causing this behavior?

Comment: sorry for late response. Could you provide a demo model for us to test with? Or this issue can happen with any model with the logic mentioned in the other post?

Comment: Sorry this is such a late response, but I wanted to revisit this issue. Yes, it seems to happen for any Navisworks-based model. I can email a model to you if it helps

Comment: yes, it will be helpful to send us a demo model and the code you are testing with. Our support channel: forge.help At autodesk.com