# Set Custom Viewpoint for Forge Model for a 360 kind-of centre location viewpoint

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55799023/is-it-possible-to-get-the-name-of-saved-views-of-nwd-models-in-forge/55804124) article, the viewpoints from a model derivative URL manifest can be obtained. But I want to create a custom viewpoint in the model since I don't have those viewpoints. My requirement is below:

I would like to create a viewpoint such that it is centered at a point(aka the **pivot**) and I should be able to look around that point in all 360 degrees, while staying at that same point (and preventing the user from moving around the model freely if possible). I have the `x,y,z` viewpoint.

- How can I create the aforementioned viewpoint?
- How do I create an upward vector?
- How do I get **aspect**, **fov** and **orthoScale**?

Also, I need to rotate the camera view based on event from another component. That component provides me data such as **pitch**, **yaw** and **roll**. How can I use that to change the camera view using the `viewer.setView()` method? Or is there any other method that needs to be used for changing the view with former parameters?

Details:

- I have a nwd file loaded in the forge viewer.
- I have the offset information available, if that plays a role in the above requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the up vector, you can get that via `viewer.avigation.getCameraUpVector()`

For aspect, fov, and orthoScale, it's similar:

```js
const aspect = viewer.navigation.getCamera().aspect;

cosnt fov = viewer.navigation.getVerticalFov();

const orthoScale = viewer.navigation.getCamera().orthoScale; //!<<< for Orthographic camera mode only
```

Comment: Also, note that you can lock certain navigation controls using https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setnavigationlocksettings-settings.