Map Navisworks camera back to Forge viewer
Following the below post, I would like to map a Navisworks camera back into Forge, so going backward.
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/map-forge-viewer-camera-back-navisworks
Does anyone know how to do it?
From my point of view, I would need to export only three variables from Navisworks to Forge in order to do this mapping. Am I right ?  enter image description here :
EDITED : In fact, I'm importing an .bcf file in order to set my view. This files is originated from Navisworks and contains the camera information.
For exemple, for an Orthographic camera it will have : camera_view_point , camera_direction, camera_up_vector , view_to_world_scale.
I got working for perspective cameras following the below answer, but for orthographic cameras I could not figure it out.
In the viewer, when I compare the cube-camera from Navisworks and Forge they are quitte simmilar, but I think there is an zooom problem.
Please, see below images.
Before zooming : https://i.sstatic.net/CUZ99pCr.png
After zooming manually : https://i.sstatic.net/WiiBONtw.png

Not sure where you got the second snapshot about the camera state, but here is the algorithm:
In Navisworks Plugin using Navisworks .NET API:
var viewpoint = Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Application.ActiveDocument.CurrentViewpoint.ToViewpoint();

var position = viewpoint.Position;
var focalDistance = viewpoint.HasFocalDistance ? viewpoint.FocalDistance : (viewpoint.NearPlaneDistance + viewpoint.FarPlaneDistance) * 0.5

var fov = 0;
var orthoScale = viewpoint.HeightField;
var isPerspective = (viewpoint.Projection == ViewpointProjection.Perspective);
if (isPerspective == true)
{
   fov = viewpoint.HeightField * (180 / Math.PI);
   orthoScale = 1;
}

var aspect = viewpoint.AspectRatio;
var rotation = viewpoint.Rotation;

// Convert the above to the below format
var data = new {
   aspect = aspect,
   isPerspective = isPerspective,
   fov = fov,
   focalDistance = focalDistance,
   position = new { x = position.X, y = position.Y, z = position.Z },
   quaternion = new { a = rotation.A, b = rotation.B, c = rotation.C, D = rotation.D },
   orthoScale = orthoScale
};

string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

In APS Viewer:
const data = JSON.parse( jsonString );
let focal = data.focalDistance;
let fov = data.fov;
let aspect = data.aspect;
let isPerspective = data.isPerspective,
let orthoScale = data.orthoScale;
let threePos = new THREE.Vector3(
    data.poistion.x,
    data.poistion.y,
    data.poistion.z,
);

let threeQN = new THREE.Quaternion(
    data.quaternion.a,
    data.quaternion.b,
    data.quaternion.c,
    data.quaternion.d,
);
 
// calculate view direction
let v1 = -2 * (threeQN.x * threeQN.z + threeQN.w * threeQN.y);
let v2 = -2 * (threeQN.y * threeQN.z - threeQN.w * threeQN.x);
let v3 = -1+ 2 * (threeQN.x * threeQN.x + threeQN.y * threeQN.y);

// calculate target
let threeTarget = new THREE.Vector3(
    threePos.x + focal * v1,
    threePos.y + focal * v2,
    threePos.z + focal * v3 
);

let model = viewer.getAllModels()[0];
let offsetMatrix = .model.getModelToViewerTransform();

let offsetPos = threePos.applyMatrix4(offsetMatrix); 
let offsetTarget = threeTarget.applyMatrix4(offsetMatrix);

// calculate up 
v1 = 2 * (threeQN.x * threeQN.y - threeQN.w * threeQN.z);
v2 = 1 - 2 * (threeQN.x*threeQN.x + threeQN.z*threeQN.z);
v3 = 2 * (threeQN.y*threeQN.z + threeQN.w*threeQN.x); 
let up = new THREE.Vector3( v1, v2, v3 );

viewer.impl.setViewFromCamera({
    aspect,
    isPerspective,
    fov,
    position: offsetPos,
    target: offsetTarget,
    up,
    orthoScale
});

Here are some related references for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804124
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/load-xml-navisworks-saved-viewpoints-forge-viewer-cameras

